# Subversion (update) performance, Windows vs. Mac. Why is the Mac version so fast?

Tags: windows, mac, svn

I’m working on a dual platform application; Windows & Macintosh). It’s a full blown application, not only a tool. So maybe it’s not huge, but at least big, lets say.

One thing I can’t put my finger on, is why is a `svn up` on a Macintosh updating this project so extremely fast?

For example, in the repository there are several `svn:externals` used, one is a repository of used libraries (like boost, CURL, libjpeg, and so on), which is approx. 9 GB in size; there are actually 3 boost versions inside.

The update of this `sub-` repository on Windows is taking longer than the full update on a Macintosh!

So is this something fundamentally different on the Macintosh—or Unix—OS, where SVN is benefiting from? Could it boil down to NTFS vs. Journaled HFS+?

Some specs, to be more specific:

- **Windows:** Quad core 2.6, 64 bit Vista, 4 GB RAM, Seagate Baracuda 7200.12 SATA, TortoiseSVN as client
- **Macintsoh:** Mac Mini, Dual core 2.0, 10.5.8, 4 GB RAM, Western Digital Scorpio Blue (WD5000BEVT), command line subversion
- **SVN Server Setup:** The SVN server reachable on LAN, both systems connected by a wired Ethernet connection with the same distance (router/switch hops).

Please note, that I have disabled on Windows: search indexing in these folders as well as anti-virus and SVN overlays only in project folder. So I did try to speed things up a little.

Comment: Have you tried a different Win based SVN client? It might just be Tortoise.

Comment: Goog question, but yes, I tried it with the windows command line svn client. Same result.

Comment: Huh, well it's still hard to eliminate implementation as a variable. The only way to figure it out now is tcpdump I suppose.